# How can I build an iPhone app with Spring Framerwork as a server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swift3

I know Java and Spring Framework.

Now I want to learn Swift so that I can build an iPhone app. The problem is that since I have 0 experience with mobile, I have a hard time to understand how an app can talk to a java server.

If there is any tutorial, I would love to learn from those.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You need to make APIs using Spring boot which do all the backend works for your applications and in your iOS app you can just invoke these APIs using appropriate Request Sending and Response handling mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

To let your app communicate with your Spring server, your server has to expose some REST APIs. If you're not familiar with REST APIs, [this](https://restfulapi.net/) can introduce you to the topic (take a look also at [this one](https://medium.com/extend/what-is-rest-a-simple-explanation-for-beginners-part-1-introduction-b4a072f8740f)).
In a nutshell, REST APIs are 'functions' that you can call outside of your server application. You can use an API for example to add a resource to your database (if any database is involved). You can than call your api from your ios application without any trouble. Consider that you can use the same APIs for example from a web application, you have only to use the client library to to HTTP call. I don't know Swift at all, take a look for example to [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-first-api-call-in-swift/) if can help to call an API from your app.
 As reference, assume that your app manages books and the user can list books, add one ad show details.

Spring (and Spring Boot, but the following is a shared features of those) provide a simple way to expose APIs in your application. You can find a basic tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

The main idea is:

1. If you need to get some information from the server, for example the book list, you have to use the HTTP GET method, which in Spring is defined with a `@GetMapping` annotation to the method that will be called by the API
2. If you need to add information to the server, for example add a new book, you have to use the HTTP POST method, which in Spring is defined with a `@PostMapping` annotation

The tutorial, provided by Spring team, will guide your through the development, if you need more details to the explanation feel free to ask; if you need a more precise help for the implementation consider to open a new question adding detail to your specific problem and link it here.